# Drupal Commerce: Create advanced add to cart form block in views

Tags: commerce

With Drupal Commerce product variations, certain values will update without a page refresh based on an attribute selection. For example, changing a color attribute may update the product image.

I want to the display the add to cart form in a views block using the method described in the following video https://drupalcommerce.org/questions/10801/display-add-cart-separate-block . At the same time I would also like to include other product fields in the block, such as price.

I am finding that the block is static and does not update based on an attribute selection. And I have tried enabling Ajax for the block without success.

Is is possible to create a dynamically updating views block to replicate some of the functionality of a commerce product display?

Comment: Does you add to cart form work when you don't use the way described in the thread you link to?

Comment: @PontusNilsson The cart from works and changes any affected values is the product display. But it does not change any values within the block

Answer (score 1):

Ajax on the block only works for the views pager and the table sorting. You have to simulate that behaviour by triggering the ajax call when an attribute is selected.

Alternatively try with Ajax Block, Block Refresh, or Authcache Blocks, and see how they trigger the Ajax load on page load, and do the same on attribute selection.